# Last marker for boto3 pagination is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm working with roles and policies using AWS boto3 SDK. I want to get the policies attached to a given role and then do some processing. Here's the code.

```
def get_policies(role_name):
    marker = None
    while True:
        print ('marker in get_policies is {} '.format(marker))
        if marker:
            response_iterator = iam.list_attached_role_policies(
                RoleName=role_name,
                # PathPrefix='string',
                Marker=marker,
                MaxItems=1
            )
        else:
            response_iterator = iam.list_attached_role_policies(
                RoleName=role_name,
                # PathPrefix='string',
                MaxItems=1
            )
        print("Next Page in get_policy : {} ".format(response_iterator['IsTruncated']))
        print(response_iterator['AttachedPolicies'])
        for policy in response_iterator['AttachedPolicies']:
            detach_policy_from_entities(policy['PolicyArn'])
            print(policy['PolicyName'] + " has to be deleted")
            # delete_policy_response = iam.delete_policy(
            #     PolicyArn=policy['PolicyArn']
            # )
            print('deleted {}'.format(policy['PolicyName']))
        if response_iterator['IsTruncated']:
            marker = response_iterator['Marker']
        else:
            print("done with policy deletion")
            return "finished"
```

The code works fine except it returns an empty list with the last marker. So, I have 3 policies attached to the given role.
The code works as follows:

1. initially marker is None, it just run the else part and returns 1 result with marker for next iteration
2. I use the marker to get another set of result. It works and returns 1 result with marker for the next iteration
3. Here I use the marker but it returns and empty list for the policy but I have one more policy

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your `detach_policy_from_entities()` function do? Perhaps it is mutating the attached role policies and hence invalidating the pagination marker. Also, why are you setting MaxItems=1? As an FYI, you should consider using the resource-level [IAM.Role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#role) as it simplifies access to the associated policies (they are available via a simple [policies](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Role.policies) property on the role).

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I'll try this.

Comment: If you're actually modifying the policies then you can change the code to simply append the policy ARNs to a list and then process that list for detachment *after* your `for policy in ...` loop completes.

Comment: Thanks, @jarmod. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mutating the attached role policies and hence invalidating the pagination marker. Also, unless you specifically need it, I would remove `MaxItems=1`.

One solution is to change the code to simply append the policy ARNs to a list and then process that list for detachment after your `for policy in ...` loop.

As an FYI, you should consider using the resource-level [IAM.Role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#role) as it simplifies access to the associated policies (they are available via simple [policies](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Role.policies) and [attached_policies](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Role.attached_policies) collections on the role). For example:

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.resource("iam")
role = iam.Role("role-name-here")

for p in role.attached_policies.all():
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with your pagination logic, but I do not think you will need pagination as by default if you do not use `MaxItems` the [list_attached_role_policies](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_attached_role_policies) function is to return 100 values.

Also, as the **Default quotas for IAM entities** defines that you can have as default 10 Managed policies attached to an IAM role, if you don't request an increment (More information IAM object quotas can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console#reference_iam-quotas-entities)).

So, for you logic works you need something like this:

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.client("iam")
role = "role_name"
policies = iam.list_attached_role_policies(RoleName=role)
policies_list = policies['AttachedPolicies']
for policy in policies_list:
    print(policy['PolicyName'])
    # you can add your detach logic here
```

Also the `list_attached_role_policies` method does not return **inline** policies, if the policies that are not being showed to you are inline policies you will need the `list_role_policies` method.

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.client("iam")
role = "role_name"
policies = iam.list_role_policies(RoleName=role)
policies_list = policies['PolicyNames']
for policy in policies_list:
    print(policy)
    # you can add your detach logic here
```

Comment: I know the default value and that I won't have any problem but I don't understand what's the issue with MaxItem=1, even with MaxItem=2 the last policy is not returned.

Comment: If your last policy is inline, you will need to use other method, I shared a example of how to return inline policies

Comment: Sorry, the problem was what @jarmod has pointed out. Thanks anyway!